# Word (2010) Update date and keep formatting using Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following VBA code to insert the date in the format of the code at the Bookmark locations. It was inserting the date each time I open the file without deleting the old Boookmark text so I added the delete text at the top of the code but now it deletes the format and it inserts the text is there a way to keep the formatting?

```
    Sub AutoOpen()
'
' AutoOpen Macro
'
'
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate1").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate2").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate3").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate4").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate5").Range.Delete
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate6").Range.Delete

      With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate").Range
         .InsertBefore Format(Date + 1, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
      End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate1").Range
        .InsertBefore Format(Date + 2, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
    End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate2").Range
        .InsertBefore Format(Date + 3, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
    End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate3").Range
        .InsertBefore Format(Date + 4, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
    End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate4").Range
       .InsertBefore Format(Date + 5, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
     End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate5").Range
       .InsertBefore Format(Date + 6, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
    End With

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate6").Range
        .InsertBefore Format(Date + 7, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: top snippet of your code deletes bookmarks so you can't run the sections of `With...` below. Am I missing something or you missed a part of your code?

Comment: KazJaw, the code runs as is. The bookmarks remain and the output of the Withs works and does what it says it does output the date in the format in the code at the places defined by each bookmark. The above is the full code that I have in the document.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'formatting' do you mean the date formatting, or bold/italic, etc?

In any case, your code doesn't run for me; when you delete the range the bookmark goes with it. The following runs for me, and correctly formats the dates each time I run it:

```
Dim tempRng As Range

Set tempRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate").Range
tempRng.Text = Format(Date + 1, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "MyDate", tempRng

Set tempRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate1").Range
tempRng.Text = Format(Date + 2, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "MyDate1", tempRng

Set tempRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyDate2").Range
tempRng.Text = Format(Date + 3, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "MyDate2", tempRng
```

You can continue it for the rest of your bookmarks or throw the whole thing in a loop.